# Double integral $\iint_{D} \left(x^2+y^2\right)\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$ over the domain $D$: $x\le x^2+y^2 \le 2x,\ \ y\ge 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

$$\iint\limits_{D} \left(x^2+y^2\right)\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$$

Where the domain is $D$: $x\le x^2+y^2 \le 2x,\ \ y\ge 0$

So far I have tried getting the bounds by working on the domain and taking the right part i could determine that $y^2+(x-1)^2 = 1$ which would be a circle, but other than that i have no idea how to work the first part of the inequality

Comment: For the first part you do the same: $(x-1/2)^2+y^2 \ge 1/4$

Comment: So the domain $D$ is outside the first circle and inside the second

Comment: Have you tried plotting it? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/odzckdmquf

Comment: So with both equations leading to a circle I can make a transformation h: $\Delta \rightarrow$ D and change to polar coordinates attempting a variable change, so I get x = r*cost, y = r*sint, where t would be the angle and I replaced in the equation so i get $cos t \le r \le 2*cost$. I can also determine that the Jacobian is r, and i get stuck, is t between 0 and pi? I'm not really sure how i should proceed with the equation even if i get t and replace in the double integral it would be something like $\iint_D r^2(cos^2t + sin^2t) * mod(Jh) rdrdt \iff \iint_D r^3 rdrdt$

Comment: You may want to use the graph to think about how to express $D$ by using polar coordinates: $r$ varies between the small circle and the large one, the angle $t$ varies along the first quadrant, right?

Comment: Hey Sorin, what helped me understand the region better and how to parametrise it is by making a sketch. Have you already tried making a sketch of the region?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to make a sketch. And also yes @WeierstraßRamirez I think so it would be between 0 and 1 so t would vary between 0 and $\pi$

Comment: @Sorin just make 2 circles: one with center $(x=1/2, y=0)$ and radius $1/2$ and another with center $(x=1, y=0)$ and radius 1

Comment: $$\int _0^1\int _{\sqrt{x-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2 x-x^2}}\left(x^2+y^2\right)dydx+\int _1^2\int _0^{\sqrt{2 x-x^2}}\left(x^2+y^2\right)dydx=\frac{45 \pi }{64}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two conditions
$$ x\le x^2+y^2\le 2x$$
collect all points $(x,y)$

- with $(x-1)^2+y^2\le 1^2$ (second inequality), which are the points inside the closed disk $D$ centered in $(1,0)$ with radius one,
- and eliminates those with $\left(x-\frac 12\right)^2 +y^2 <\left(\frac 12\right)^2$, so we cut the disk $D'$ centered in $\left(\frac 12,0\right)$ and radius $\frac 12$.

The picture for these two conditions only is:

```
sage: x, y = var('x,y');
sage: region_plot([ x <= x^2 + y^2 , x^2 + y^2 <= 2*x ], (x, -3, 3), (y, -3, 3) )
Launched png viewer for Graphics object consisting of 1 graphics primitive
```

[image]

We further have to restrict to the part $y\ge 0$.
But note the symmetry of both the blue domain $D$ above, and of the function under the integral w.r.t. the $Ox$ axis. So we may integrate on $D-D'$, and take half of the result.

---

The integral to be computed, call it
$$
J
\ ,$$
is a difference of two integrals. Each of the two integrals can be then computed

- by either splitting the variables via Cavalieri / Fubini, and to have a simpler bound among the two, we may want to use the symmetry w.r.t. the $Ox$-axis, and start in $y=0$,
- or by passing to polar coordinates

  - on $D$ substitute $\left\{\begin{aligned}x &= 1+r\sin t\\y&=r\cos t\end{aligned}\right.$ where $r\in(0,1)$ and $t\in(0,2\pi)$, $dx\wedge dy=(\sin t\; dr+r\cos t\; dt)
    \wedge(\cos t\; dr-r\sin t\; dt)=r\;dt\wedge dr$
  - on $D'$  substitute $\left\{\begin{aligned}x &= 1/2+r\sin t\\y&=r\cos t\end{aligned}\right.$ where $r\in(0,1/2)$ and $t\in0,2\pi)$, $dx\wedge dy=(\sin t\; dr+r\cos t\; dt)
    \wedge(\cos t\; dr-r\sin t\; dt)=r\;dt\wedge dr$:

  We will integrate on the whole blue part, so that in case the sine integral appearing is done on a full period, and vanishes $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin t\; dt=0$. Alternatively, we may switch $\sin$ and $\cos$ in the polar coordinate parametrizations.
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  J&=\frac 12\int_{D-D'}(x^2 +y^2)\; dx\; dy
  \\
  &=
  \frac 12\int_{D}(x^2 +y^2)\; dx\; dy
  -
  \frac 12\int_{D'}(x^2 +y^2)\; dx\; dy
  \\
  &=
  \int_{D\ :\ x\ge 0}(x^2 +y^2)\; dx\; dy
  -
  \int_{D'\ :\ x\ge 0}(x^2 +y^2)\; dx\; dy
  \\
  &=
  \int_{x=0}^{x=2}dx\int_{y=0}^{y=\sqrt{2x-x^2}}(x^2+ y^2)\; dy
  -
  \int_{x=0}^{x=1}dx\int_{y=0}^{y=\sqrt{x-x^2}}(x^2+ y^2)\; dy
  \\
  &=
  \int_{x=0}^{x=2}dx\left[x^2y +\frac 13y^3\right]_{y=0}^{y=\sqrt{2x-x^2}}
  -
  \int_{x=0}^{x=1}dx\left[x^2y +\frac 13y^3\right]_{y=0}^{y=\sqrt{x-x^2}}
  \\
  &=
  \int_0^2 dx\left[x^2 +\frac 13(2x-x^2)\right]\sqrt{2x-x^2}
  -
  \int_0^1 dx\left[x^2 +\frac 13(x-x^2)\right]\sqrt{x-x^2}
  \\
  &=
  \cdot\frac{3\pi}{4}
  -
  \cdot\frac{3\pi}{64}
  =
  \frac{3(16-1)\pi}{64}
  =
  \bbox[yellow]{\ \frac{45\pi}{64}\ }\ .
  \\[4mm]
  &\qquad\qquad\text{ Alternatively:}
  \\[4mm]
  J&=\frac 12\int_{D-D'}(x^2 +y^2)\; dx\; dy
  \\
  &=
  \frac 12\int_{D}(x^2 +y^2)\; dx\; dy
  -
  \frac 12\int_{D'}(x^2 +y^2)\; dx\; dy
  \\
  &=
  \frac 12\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}(1+2r\sin t+r^2)\; r\; dt\; dr
  -
  \frac 12\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac 14+r\sin t+r^2\right)\; r\; dt\; dr
  \\
  &=
  \pi\int_0^1(1+r^2)\; r\; dr
  -
  \pi\int_0^{1/2}\left(\frac 14+r^2\right)\; r\; dr
  \\
  &=
  \pi\left[\frac 12r^2+\frac 14r^4\right]_0^1
  -
  \pi\left[\frac 18r^2+\frac 14r^4\right]_0^{1/2}
  \\
  &=
  \pi\left[\frac 12+\frac 14\right]
  -
  \pi\left[\frac 1{32}+\frac 1{64}\right]
  =
  \bbox[yellow]{\ \frac{45\pi}{64}\ }\ .
  \end{aligned}
  $$

Comment: Did you forget to restrict to $y\geq 0$?

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez Oh, yes, thanks for pointing it out, i have to edit...

Comment: I was confused by that as well indeed, the answer is right and it's the best explanation thank you

Answer (score 2):

After plotting the region I find it can be expressed in polar coordinates as $\cos\theta<r<2\cos\theta$ and $0<\theta<\pi/2$.
Integrating in polar over this region we get $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_{\cos\theta}^{2\cos\theta} r^2 \cdot rdr.$$
This is not too hard except for when you have to integrate $\cos^4\theta$. At this point you can repeatedly apply the power-reduction identity $\cos^2 x = (1+\cos(2x))/2$ (first to $\cos\theta$ and then to $\cos(2\theta))$.
My answer ends up being $45\pi/64$.

Comment: You can find the polar bounds, e.g., by writing $x^2 + y^2 > x$ as $r^2 > r\cos\theta$, which implies $r>\cos\theta$.

Comment: I did it now it seems there were multiple ways to go about it but after finding the bounds of the angle i reached $45\pi/64$, since i gave up the method and tried with Fubini but returned after i realised what I was missing, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The idea is writing the region D as the region between two functions of $x$, to integrate with Fubini's theorem.
From the first innequality we have:
$$x \leq x^2 + y^2$$
$$ y \geq\sqrt{x - x^2}$$
for $0\leq x \leq 1$, else the radicand would be negative. Now the second inneuquality yields:
$$2x \geq x^2 + y^2$$
$$ y \leq\sqrt{2x-x^2}$$
for $0\leq x \leq 2$
Now we can write
$$D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2| 0 \leq x \leq 1, \sqrt{x - x^2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{2x-x^2}\} \bigcup \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2| 1 \leq x \leq 2,  \leq y \leq \sqrt{2x-x^2}\}$$

Now you can use Fubini's theorem to evaluate the integral as:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\sqrt{x - x^2}}^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}} (y^2 + x^2)dydx + \int_{1}^{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}} (y^2 + x^2)dydx$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hi, can you point out what exactly is wrong?

Comment: I see. The region D I wrote doesn't include the case where $x<1$ and $x^2 + y^2 \geq x$. I'll add that

Comment: After doing the integrals i got the answer, the original answer you had provided gave me something else entirely because of the two cases. Thank you for your work